# Autofac wiring question - beginner

Tags: autofac

Beginners question:
Given two classes: Myclass5 and Myclass6 how can one wire up following factory method (returned as Func) 
such that 
myclass5 and myclass6 instances and IMyClass that they depend on are all retrieved via autofac (assuming that these three instances are registered).

```
   public static MyClass4 FactoryMethod(int nu)
    {
        if (nu == 1)
            return new MyClass5(....);
        if (nu == 4)
            return new MyClass6(....);

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

public abstract class MyClass4
{

}

public class MyClass5 : MyClass4
{
    public MyClass5(int nu, IMyClass a)
    {

    }
}

public class MyClass6 : MyClass4
{
    public MyClass6(int nu, IMyClass a)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `FactoryMethod` to be able to create the instances, it requires access to a container. I would suggest create a delegate type for the factory method, which makes it easy to take dependency on it. Registration goes like this:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<SomeClass>().As<IMyClass>();
cb.RegisterType<MyClass5>();
cb.RegisterType<MyClass6>();
cb.Register((c, p) =>
    {
        var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return new FactoryMethod(nu =>
            {
                var nuParameter = TypedParameter.From(nu);
                switch (nu)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return context.Resolve<MyClass5>(nuParameter);
                    case 4:
                        return context.Resolve<MyClass6>(nuParameter);
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            });
        });

var container = cb.Build();
```

At resolve time, you can then take a dependency on the `FactoryMethod` delegate type and use it to resolve instances:

```
var factory = container.Resolve<FactoryMethod>();
var instance5 = factory(1);
var instance6 = factory(1);
```

Note: the delegate instance we're creating needs a context. We cannot use the `c` parameter directly since that context is only temporary. Thus we must resolve a `IComponentContext` to "bake" into the lambda.

**Update:** if you would like to extract the factory implementation into a method that is not dependent on the container I would suggest the following:

```
    public class FactoryMethodImpl
    {
        readonly Func<int, MyClass5> _factory5;
        readonly Func<int, MyClass6> _factory6;

        public FactoryMethodImpl(Func<int, MyClass5> factory5, Func<int, MyClass6> factory6)
        {
            _factory5 = factory5;
            _factory6 = factory6;
        }

        public MyClass4 Create(int nu)
        {
            switch (nu)
            {
                case 1:
                    return _factory5(nu);
                case 4:
                    return _factory6(nu);
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, change the registration code to this:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<SomeClass>().As<IMyClass>();
cb.RegisterType<MyClass5>();
cb.RegisterType<MyClass6>();
cb.RegisterType<FactoryMethodImpl>().SingleInstance();
cb.Register(c=> new FactoryMethod(c.Resolve<FactoryMethodImpl>().Create));
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I have no choice but to create the FactoryMethod type. But i would like this factory method to be part of my code but if I do that then I would have to carry Autofacs IComponentContext in my code. Any work around this situation?

Comment: @user645788: see my updated answer. I'd say, with Autofac there's always a choice ;)

Comment: @user645788: glad to be of assistance :) Please mark my answer as accepted, if this solved your problem.